# SQL Query in Grails to fetch all data from two tables which are in Foreign key relations

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails

I completely new to Grails framework so I faced one problem from last 4 days onward, Actually my requirement is I have two tables 
**1. Stock Table.
2. Warehouse Table.**

I am fetching **Stock** table records including **Warehouse** table.

There is a foreign key relation between two tables.
(warehouse_id====>present in Stock Table).
[My Grails class==>links[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhLXA.jpg)

And I want all the column records from both the tables in a single list with the help of SQL/HQL/Criteria/ or Native SQL.

I tried multiple times but I am getting only **Stock** table records but not **Warehouse** table records.
[Stock table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRN7g.jpg)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it, but i suggest trying out Grails Criteria Projections, here is a similar issue solution:

[Grails Criteria projections on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895091/grails-criteria-projections-on-joined-table)

Comment: Hi as per your suggestion i implemented the Grails Criteria Projections and now its working fine. But suppose i want to add where clause then how to implement this functionality. Means= where "id"=8 (just example).

Comment: It will look something like this eq ('id', 8), there are a lot of exmaples:
http://grails.asia/grails-criteria-projections-examples